C++ Project Library
I'm creating a C++ project called Library and I have a few problems with the code. I've implemented every part of the task and the issue comes with the right implementation of the code. Here are the classes:
Book.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Reader;

class Book {
protected:
string title;
string author;
int publishingYear;
bool isRented;
Reader* reader;
char returnDate[17];

public:
Book();
Book(string title, string author, int year);
void printData();
void rentBook(Reader* r,char returnDate);
void returnBook();
bool isAvailable();
string getTitle();
};

Book.cpp
#include "Book.h"
#include "Reader.h"
using namespace std;

Book::Book() : title(""), author(""), publishingYear(0), isRented(false), 
reader(nullptr), returnDate("") {}

Book::Book(string title, string author, int year)
: title(title), author(author), publishingYear(year), isRented(false), reader(nullptr), 
returnDate("") {}

void Book::printData() {
std::cout << "Title: " << title << ", Author: " << author
    << ", Year: " << publishingYear
    << ", Status: " << (isRented ? "Rented" : "Available")
    << (isRented ? ", Reader: " + reader->getFullName() + ", Return Date: " + 
returnDate : "")
    << endl;
}

void Book::rentBook(Reader* r, char returnDate) {
isRented = true;
reader = r;
returnDate = returnDate;
}

void Book::returnBook() {
isRented = false;
reader = nullptr;
returnDate = "";
}

bool Book::isAvailable() {
return !isRented;
}

std::string Book::getTitle() {
return title;
}

Fiction.h
#include "Book.h"
using namespace std;

class Fiction : public Book {
private:
string genre;

public:
Fiction();
Fiction(string title, string author, int year, string genre);
void printData();
};

Fiction.cpp
#include "Fiction.h"
using namespace std;

Fiction::Fiction() : Book(), genre("") {}

Fiction::Fiction(string title, string author, int year, string genre)
: Book(title, author, year), genre(genre) {}

void Fiction::printData() {
Book::printData();
cout << "Genre: " << genre << endl;
}

Scientific.h
#include "Book.h"
using namespace std;

class Scientific : public Book {
private:
string scientificArea;
string ISBN;

public:
Scientific();
Scientific(string title, string author, int year, string area, string isbn);
void printData();
};

Scientific.cpp
#include "Scientific.h"

Scientific::Scientific() : Book(), scientificArea(""), ISBN("") {}

Scientific::Scientific(std::string title, std::string author, int year, std::string 
area, std::string isbn)
: Book(title, author, year), scientificArea(area), ISBN(isbn) {}

void Scientific::printData() {
Book::printData();
std::cout << "Scientific Area: " << scientificArea << ", ISBN: " << ISBN << std::endl;
}

Reader.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Book.h"
using namespace std;

class Reader {
private:
string firstName;
string lastName;
int age;
Book* rentedBooks[100];
int numberOfRentedBooks;

public:
Reader();
Reader(string firstName, string lastName, int age);
void addBook(Book* book);
void returnBook(Book* book);
void printRentedBooks();
string getFullName();
int getNumberOfRentedBooks();
bool hasReadBook(Book* book);

Reader.cpp
#include "Reader.h"
using namespace std;

Reader::Reader() : firstName(""), lastName(""), age(0), numberOfRentedBooks(0) {
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    rentedBooks[i] = nullptr;
}
}

Reader::Reader(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
: firstName(firstName), lastName(lastName), age(age), numberOfRentedBooks(0) {
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    rentedBooks[i] = nullptr;
}
}

void Reader::addBook(Book* book) {
if (numberOfRentedBooks < 100) {
    rentedBooks[numberOfRentedBooks++] = book;
}
}

void Reader::returnBook(Book* book) {
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRentedBooks; i++) {
    if (rentedBooks[i] == book) {
        rentedBooks[i] = nullptr;
        numberOfRentedBooks--;
        break;
    }
}
}

void Reader::printRentedBooks() {
std::cout << "Rented Books by " << getFullName() << ":" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRentedBooks; i++) {
    if (rentedBooks[i] != nullptr) {
        rentedBooks[i]->printData();
    }
}
}

std::string Reader::getFullName() {
return firstName + " " + lastName;
}

int Reader::getNumberOfRentedBooks() {
return numberOfRentedBooks;
}

bool Reader::hasReadBook(Book* book) {
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRentedBooks; i++) {
    if (rentedBooks[i] == book) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

Library.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Book.h"
#include "Reader.h"
using namespace std;

class Library {
private:
string name;
string address;
Book* books[100];
int numberOfBooks;
Reader* readers[100];
int numberOfReaders;

public:
Library();
Library(string name, string address);
void addBook(Book* book);
void addReader(Reader* reader);
Book* searchBookByTitle(string& title);
Book** getBooks();
int getNumberOfBooks();
void printMostReadReader();
void printMostReadBook();
};

Library.cpp
#include "Library.h"
using namespace std;

Library::Library() : name(""), address(""), numberOfBooks(0), numberOfReaders(0) {
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    books[i] = nullptr;
    readers[i] = nullptr;
}
}

Library::Library(string name, string address)
: name(name), address(address), numberOfBooks(0), numberOfReaders(0) {
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    books[i] = nullptr;
    readers[i] = nullptr;
}
}

void Library::addBook(Book* book) {
if (numberOfBooks < 100) {
    books[numberOfBooks++] = book;
}
}

void Library::addReader(Reader* reader) {
if (numberOfReaders < 100) {
    readers[numberOfReaders++] = reader;
}
}

Book* Library::searchBookByTitle(string& title) {
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBooks; i++) {
    if (books[i] != nullptr && books[i]->getTitle() == title) {
        return books[i];
    }
}
return nullptr;
}

Book** Library::getBooks() {
return books; 
}

int Library::getNumberOfBooks() {
return numberOfBooks;
}

void Library::printMostReadReader() {
int maxBooks = 0;
Reader* mostReadReader = nullptr;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReaders; i++) {
    if (readers[i] != nullptr) {
        int count = readers[i]->getNumberOfRentedBooks();
        if (count > maxBooks) {
            maxBooks = count;
            mostReadReader = readers[i];
        }
    }
}

if (mostReadReader != nullptr) {
    cout << "Most read reader: " << mostReadReader->getFullName() << " with " << 
maxBooks << " books." << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "No readers found." << endl;
}
}

void Library::printMostReadBook() {
int maxCount = 0;
Book* mostReadBook = nullptr;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBooks; i++) {
    if (books[i] != nullptr) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfReaders; j++) {
            if (readers[j] != nullptr && readers[j]->hasReadBook(books[i])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            mostReadBook = books[i];
        }
    }
}

if (mostReadBook != nullptr) {
    cout << "Most read book: " << mostReadBook->getTitle() << " with " << maxCount << " 
readers." << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "No books found." << endl;
}

}
Main.cpp
#include "Fiction.h"
#include "Scientific.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
Library library("City Library", "123 Main St");

Reader* reader1 = new Reader("John", "Doe", 25);
library.addReader(reader1);

Book* book1 = new Fiction("The Great Gatsby", "F. Scott Fitzgerald", 1925, "Novel");
library.addBook(book1);

Book* book2 = new Scientific("A Brief History of Time", "Stephen Hawking", 1988, 
"Physics", "978-0553109535");
library.addBook(book2);

book1->printData();
book2->printData();

book1->rentBook(reader1, "2023.12.31");
reader1->addBook(book1);
book1->printData();

std::cout << "Available books:" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < library.getNumberOfBooks(); i++) {
    if (library.getBooks()[i]->isAvailable()) {
        library.getBooks()[i]->printData();
    }
}

library.printMostReadReader();
library.printMostReadBook();

return 0;
}


You say that you have problems, but you don't tell us about the problems you have. Or even ask us a question. And the title doesn't really summarize your question. Please take some time to refresh the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist. And don't forget how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the minimal part, and how to [edit] your questions.

Way too much code, and a lot of unecesarry uses of new/delete and pointers, almost like you learned Jave or C# first. Whoever taught this was a good idea Book** getBooks(); is not teaching you C++, and should learn about std::vector<Book>.  Show him or her this : CppCon 2015: Kate Gregory “Stop Teaching C". So I think your main problem at the moment is not knowing enough C++

Nitpick:  You have using namespace std; in header files.  1) don't have using namespace std as it allows for the entirety of the std namespace, thus nullifying the purpose of namespaces. 2) Every translation unit that includes the header will also have this statement.

I highly recommend creating an [mcve] with small pieces, like Book, get it working, then back it up.  Add small pieces and repeat.  FYI, I was under the impression that Library in your title meant collections of code, such as GMP.

You clicked [Ask Question], but you haven't asked a question.
